# NSFetchedResultsController - Incomplete UI update in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to refresh the data of a table view. The data itself is provided via an XML parser that runs on the background. After the parser finished, it saves the data into its own context. The `NSFetchedResultsController` picks up these changes immediately and starts calling the `-(void)controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` delegate method for each updated element. This also is fast and looks totally normal in the log files.

However, in `-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:` I call `UITableView`'s `-(void)endUpdates`. Then I see the update animation on the screen, but in all cells, beside the last one which is only half visible, the only thing that is visible is an image on the left side of the cell. All text labels are not visible. It takes about 5 to 10 seconds, then all the labels pop visible.

However if I ignore all the delegate calls of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and simply call `[self.tableView reloadData]` on `-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:` everything works without problems. The content is there immediately.

Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong here? The profiler shows that the main thread is basically doing nothing. Touch events are handled properly, besides the events that are dispatched to the table view. These aren't handled. It seems like the table view is busy doing some serious work, but I really don't know what that could be, as the animation is already done.

Here is my implementation of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    UITableView* tableView = self.tableView;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    [(NewsItemCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] updateWithNews:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And this is the code of my cell layout:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    News* model = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NewsItemCell* cell = (NewsItemCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NewsCellReuseIdentifier];
    [cell updateWithNews:model];
    cell.accessoryType = (model.content ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone);
    return cell;
}
```

And the pretty basic update of the cell:

```
- (void)updateWithNews:(News*)news {
    NSString* dateString = [[NSDateFormatter outputDateFormatter] stringFromDate:news.date];
    self.headlineLabel.text = (news.headline ? news.headline : NSLocalizedString(@"<NewsNoHeadlineReplacement>", nil));
    self.metaInfoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"<NewsMetaInfoFormatDate>", nil), (dateString ? dateString : (NSLocalizedString(@"<NewsNoDateReplacement>", nil)))];

    self.readIndicatorView.hidden = (news.read != nil && [news.read compare:news.parsingDate] == NSOrderedDescending);
}
```

The placeholder strings aren't shown either. The labels are completely empty. Only the image is visible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things I would check first:

1. Make sure your fetch is not executed in a different thread
2. Make sure your fetch is quick, if it's too slow it might be the cause as well

Comment: I am doing my fetch in the main thread and the console shows that the data is already there. The screen isn't updated AFTER a call to `endUpdates`.

Comment: Please print your thread id in didChangeObject like so: `NSLog(@"current = %@, main = %@", [NSThread currentThread], [NSThread mainThread]);`, verify it's the same thread, if not then that is your issue.

Comment: Ok those two threads are NOT the same. Mh... I am getting an idea of what is going on. Thanks for your help so far. I am merging my contexts on the thread, the notification appears. I think this might trigger the `NSFetchedResultsController` in the same thread!? So I have to keep an instance of the thread the context is for, to call the merging in this specific thread?

Comment: Yes the problem is that notificaton method is called in your bg thread. Try adding `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [mainThreadContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification]; });` to your notification method

Comment: What I did now is: I have a `BCAutoMergingManagedObjectContext` that merges itself on changes from other automerging context's. This context now has a weak reference to the thread it was initialized in and always dispatches merging into this thread synchronously if it isn't already executing in it. This seems to solve the problem. I hope this wouldn't have any other side effects. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Let's focus on this piece of code:

```
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [(NewsItemCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] updateWithNews:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        break;
```

To walk you through what's happening:

1. you open updates transaction on tableView
2. then you react to delegate calls by issuing commands to tableView
3. *but for updates you do it differently by issuing commands not related to tableView*
4. then you close transaction on tableView

What I mean is: tableView commands may bundle the changes into one transaction. Seems like your calls to rerender cells are ending up on the next transaction. So replace the code above with:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic ];
        break;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The behaviour is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Hmmm, can you log tableView transactions and changes commited in them? It may happen that certain data is loaded in one transaction and the rest in the next.

Comment: It turns out the calls come in on another thread. See Tomasz Zabłocki answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are your calls to your NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in a background thread? That might be the issue. To test, you could merge the changes of your bg moc into the main moc and observe the main moc instead of the bg moc. An instance of a NSManagedObjectContext is only supposed to be used by one thread.

Comment: You say you parse in a background thread moc. Then I assume your NSfrc is monitoring that bg moc. Then the calls to that frc are going to be made in the bg (they should). Is this correct? If this is so, you are using frc in the bg.

Comment: No, the `NSFetchedResultsController` is using a different NSManagedObjectContext, but see my comment on the answer from Tomasz Zablocki. In deed it is a different thread...